# run nginx in port different than apache port

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, nginx

I want to know how to run nginx on different port than apache port

For example when someone go to link

```
http://site.com
```

It will be served as apache

If he go to the link

```
http://site.com:81
```

The page served as nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find what you need here:

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic#sph_server-configuration

and here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html